# ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED calls my $http sucess function

Tags: angularjs, angular-http

Running my Angular app without a server running should return an error, or course. But this "ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED" I see in my Chrome's console triggers my success function of my membership service:

```
    function login(user, onSuccess, onError){
        $http.post(_loginAddress, user)
             .success(loginSuccess)
             .success(onSuccess)
             .error(loginError)
             .error(onError);
    }
    function loginSuccess(data) {
        // this code executes with data = null here.
        if (data.ok === true) {
            ...
        }
    }
    function loginError(data, code) {
        ...
    }
```

The relevant section of the [$http docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#post) states:

> A response status code between 200 and 299 is considered a success status and will result in the success callback being called. Note that if the response is a redirect, XMLHttpRequest will transparently follow it, meaning that the error callback will not be called for such responses.

Am I suppose to program my $http success() functions for possible false-positive?

**EDIT**

[image]

Comment: Can't reproduce: http://plnkr.co/edit/lnz7DUL6G0G9bEONvH4q?p=preview. Open the console: you'll see the `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` error, but you'll also see that the error callback is called, and not the success callback.

Comment: Thanks JB for trying to reproduce it. I've added a screenshot of what I'm seeing in my own environment. I'm truly am clueless about how I'm getting it.

Answer (score 4):

So .. I went hunting and found that one of my interceptors (authentication) was causing this ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED error response to be considered as 'recovered' and therefore the success function was called.

I changed this:

```
if (response.status !== 401) {
    return response;
}
```

To this:

```
if (response.status !== 401) {
    return $q.reject(response);
}
```

And everything is fine again.

Hope this might help someone else.